# How to determine that a time slot available or not using C# Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Let's say there is a table name ClassRoutineTable:

```
RoomId     DayId     StartTime      EndTime

 1          1        08.00.00       10.00.00
 1          1        12.00.00       14.00.00
 2          1        10.00.00       12.00.00
```

Now, I need to check whether the Time slot are available or not for specific room and day. for example, if I do input start time or end time 08.00.00 or 10.00.00 or in between this two time (i.e start time or end time 09.00.00) for the room and day id 1 ;that will return a message that Time slot is not available otherwise it will save. 
For Instance I trying something like this:

```
public string SaveRoom(Allocation allocation)
    {

        List<Allocation> checckAllocations =
            roomAllocationGateway.GetAllAllocations()
                .Where(
                    x =>
                        x.RoomId == allocation.RoomId && x.DayId == allocation.DayId && "*Code for Check time slot  *"
                       )
                .ToList();
        if (checckAllocations.Count >0)
        {
             return "Time Slot Not Available";

        }
        roomAllocationGateway.SaveRoom(allocation);
            return "saved";
    }
```

Comment: Are StartTime and EndTime strings or DateTime objects?

Comment: Date Time Object @Kel

Comment: Looks like a correct answer was already provided, but as a side note you can replace .Where() method call and .Count > 0 condition with .Any() method call

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully help you

```
public string SaveRoom(Allocation allocation)
    {

        List<Allocation> checckAllocations =
            roomAllocationGateway.GetAllAllocations()
                .Where(
                    x =>
                        x.RoomId == allocation.RoomId && x.DayId == allocation.DayId && x.StartTime<=allocation.EndTime &&  allocation.StartTime<=x.EndTime
                       )
                .ToList();
        if (checckAllocations.Count >0)
        {
             return "Time Slot Not Available";

        }
        roomAllocationGateway.SaveRoom(allocation);
            return "saved";
    }
```

Comment: does "SaveRoom" function use in Update case . If has , you must add " && x.Id !=allocation.Id" where Id is your primarykey's table

Answer (score 0):

Let 's try below code, Hope it helps you :

```
public string SaveRoom(Allocation allocation) {
    //allocation.StartTime=08.00.00 
    //allocation.EndTime =10.00.00 
    List < Allocation > checckAllocations =
        roomAllocationGateway.GetAllAllocations()
        .Where(
            x = >
            x.RoomId == allocation.RoomId && x.DayId == allocation.DayId && ((x.startTime <= allocation.StartTime && x.startTime <= allocation.EndTime) || (x.endTime >= allocation.StartTime && x.endTime >= allocation.EndTime))
    )
        .ToList();
    if (checckAllocations.Count > 0) {
        return "Time Slot Not Available";
    }
    roomAllocationGateway.SaveRoom(allocation);
    return "saved";
}
```

Comment: It's not working, It always Return "Time Slot Not Available" although it's available. @Sunil

Comment: What starttime and endtime you are using ?

Comment: It need to check for any start or end time. say if I input 04.00.00 and 05.00.00 it will save but for 09.00.00 and 11.00.00 this show not available message thus 09.00.00 is in between 08.00.00 and 10.00.00 which already assign for a course in database. @Sunil